# using a variable for size of image in img_url in liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to display an image in my shopify store with an aspect ratio of 4:1, but because I cannot know to image's size I am using the following code:

```
{% assign h = image_object.width | divided_by: 4 %}
{% assign size = image_object.width | append: "x" | append: h | strip %}
<img src="{{ image_object | img_url: size ,crop: 'center'}}">
```

but this doesn't work. The image stays in its original size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `divided_by` was returning a non-integer number which doesn't work with `img_url`. adding `| floor` solved the problem.